# Auto Adjust screen for different tablets.

Tags: android, layout, tablet

My application runs and displays correctly for on my testing device (Nexus 10 tablet). I need my layouts to fit on these tablets: Nexus 10, 7, Samsung 7, Samsung 10. I am using relative layouts. API min 16 API target 19. I have tried to adjust my layouts to fit other sizes by making changes in my Android Manifest. Here are two snippets.

```
  <supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>


<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.wollan.afipresents.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation = "landscape"
        android:icon="@drawable/menuiconplain" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout-sw600dp and a layout-720dp folders and this will enable your layouts for 7 and 10 inches tablets.

You can also check this link : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

It helped me alot